# Can I generate a regression test suite automatically?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, regression-testing, zimbra

We're looking at an upgrade from zimbra 6 to zimbra 7, and we want to avoid regressions in the account lifecycle software we wrote to integrate with it. Since most things are documented by a WSDL file, we were thinking of just using that to test.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to use an API definition and two target servers to populate a test suite?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).  It is an open source product that can do some automated testing based on a WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a combination of the below three tools to solve the kind of problem you have mentioned

1. [Model Based Testing](http://goldpractice.thedacs.com/practices/mbt/)
2. Define graphic model and MBT based code gen using [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) and use [GraphWalker](http://graphwalker.org/) to generate the tests dynamically bu walking the model
3. [Spock testing framework](http://spockframework.org) + [spring-ws](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/)

I've used soapUI extensively but it is not very flexible for code gen related tests. It is however super to create the tests once, parameterize them and maintain overtime by checking in the soapui project to version control

Comment: From the yEd "The Software may not be used as part of an automated process." Thoughts?